# How to make a dynamic form for user in flask

Tags: python, database, flask, jinja2

I have the edit button for every user in table and I want to use only one edit form for all of them.
My edit button implementation:

```
{{ button_show_dialog('open_edit_sprint_user', 'Edit','btn-primary') }}

{% call dialog_window('open_edit_sprint_user', 'Edit') %} {{ wtf.quick_form(edit_sprint_user_form, button_map={'add_user-submit': 'success'}) }} {% endcall %}
```

**sprint_handler.py**

```
def sprint_info(team_code, sprint_number):
    edit_sprint_user_form = forms.EditSprintUserForm(prefix='edit_sprint_user')
    if edit_sprint_user_form.validate_on_submit():
        ******do something******
    return render_template('baseop/sprint_info.html', sprint=sprint,
            edit_sprint_user_form=edit_sprint_user_form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditSprintUserForm(FlaskForm):
    value = FloatField('Mark', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Edit')
```

I've got a function that returns all users in my sprint `get_users_in_sprint()`

So I want to press this button and edit different users with only one form named EditSprintUserForm , but now I can edit only one selected person

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, I think the key will be to obtain the current edited user's username or id when you click the edit button.

The simple solution is to use JavaScript, you will need to create a hidden field for your form to get username or id:

```py
from wtforms import HiddenField

class EditSprintUserForm(FlaskForm):
    user = HiddenField('User')  # <--
    value = FloatField('Mark', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Edit')
```

Then create an event listener with JavaScript to fill this hidden input with username or id when you click the edit button. You can store user's username or id in the edit button.

Now in the view function, you can get the username or id with `edit_sprint_user_form.user.data`.